# R-- Add leading zero to string, with no fixed string format

Tags: r, leading-zero

I have a column as below.

9453, 55489, 4588, 18893, 4457, 2339, 45489HQ, 7833HQ

I would like to add leading zero if the number is less than 5 digits. However, some numbers have "HQ" in the end, some don't.(I did check other posts, they dont have similar problem in the "HQ" part)

so the finally desired output should be:

09453, 55489, 04588, 18893, 04457, 02339, 45489HQ, 07833HQ

any idea how to do this? Thank you so much for reading my post!

Comment: Not exactly the same, as that question doesn't answer the case if there are letters after the number.

Comment: @RichScriven I did check the post, it is not the same problem. I have the "HQ" problem with no fixed length. it is NOT a duplicate question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A one-liner using regular expressions:

```
my_strings <- c("9453", "55489", "4588", 
      "18893", "4457", "2339", "45489HQ", "7833HQ")

gsub("^([0-9]{1,4})(HQ|$)", "0\\1\\2",my_strings)

[1] "09453"   "55489"   "04588"   "18893"   
    "04457"   "02339"   "45489HQ" "07833HQ"
```

Explanation:

```
^ start of string
[0-9]{1,4} one to four numbers in a row
(HQ|$) the string "HQ" or the end of the string
```

Parentheses represent capture groups in order.  So `0\\1\\2` means `0` followed by the first capture group `[0-9]{1,4}` and the second capture group `HQ|$`.

Of course if there is 5 numbers, then the regex isn't matched, so it doesn't change.

Comment: A good solution, although this won't work if the number is less than 4 digits. OP should probably clarify if they have 3 or less digits in any case.

Comment: Try `my_strings %>% paste("0000", ., sep='') %>% gsub("^.*([0-9]{5})(HQ|$)", "\\1\\2", .)`. It will work for any number of digits ;)

Answer (score 5):

I was going to use the `sprintf` approach, but found the the `stringr` package provides a very easy solution.

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("9453", "55489", "4588", "18893", "4457", "2339", "45489HQ", "7833HQ")
[1] "9453"    "55489"   "4588"    "18893"   "4457"    "2339"    "45489HQ" "7833HQ"
```

This can be converted with one simple `stringr::str_pad()` function:

```
stringr::str_pad(x, 5, side="left", pad="0")
[1] "09453"   "55489"   "04588"   "18893"   "04457"   "02339"   "45489HQ" "7833HQ"
```

If the number needs to be padded even if the total string width is >5, then the number and text need to be separated with regex.
The following will work. It combines regex matching with the very helpful `sprintf()` function:

```
sprintf("%05.0f%s", # this encodes the format and recombines the number with padding (%05.0f) with text(%s)
        as.numeric(gsub("^(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)), #get the number
        gsub("[[:digit:]]+([a-zA-Z]*)$", "\\1", x)) #get just the text at the end
[1] "09453"   "55489"   "04588"   "18893"   "04457"   "02339"   "45489HQ" "07833HQ"
```

Comment: Expected `07833HQ` instead of "7833HQ"

Comment: ah- thanks, it does look like this approach won't work if that is the desired output, and some regex is needed to split the numeric portion out. The other answers accomplish that nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt, which will also work in cases like `"123"` or `"1HQR"`:

```
x <- c("18893","4457","45489HQ","7833HQ","123", "1HQR")
regmatches(x, regexpr("^\\d+", x)) <- sprintf("%05d", as.numeric(sub("\\D+$","",x)))
x
#[1] "18893"    "04457"    "45489HQ"  "07833HQ"  "00123"    "00001HQR"
```

This basically finds any numbers at the start of the string (`^\\d+`) and replaces them with a zero-padded (via `sprintf`) string that was subset out by removing any non-numeric characters (`\\D+$`) from the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

We can use only `sprintf()` and `gsub()` by splitting up the parts then putting them back together.

```
sprintf("%05d%s", as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", x)), gsub("[0-9]+", "", x))
# [1] "18893"    "04457"    "45489HQ"  "07833HQ"  "00123"    "00001HQR"
```

Using @thelatemail's data:

```
x <- c("18893", "4457", "45489HQ", "7833HQ", "123", "1HQR")
```

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't get to use `regmatches<-`, which automatically earns you 10 "obscure R" points. This is probably cleaner really.

Comment: Yeah but I noticed that this method is in another answer.  Regex is cleaner here though.